# How to simplify repetitive OR condition in Where(e => e.prop1.contains() || e.prop2.contains() || ...)

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, entity-framework-core

I have a lot of code like this:

```
IQueryable<MyEntity> query...
query.Where(e => EF.Functions.Like(e.Property1,  pattern)
                || EF.Functions.Like(e.Property2, pattern)
                || EF.Functions.Like(e.Property3, pattern)
                ...);
```

How can I simplify it to remove the repetitive code to something like this:

```
query.Where(Search(pattern, e => e.Property1, e => e.Property2, e => e.Property3));
```

or

```
query.Where(e => Search(pattern, e.Property1,  e.Property2,  e.Property3))
```

EDIT: The query must be translated to SQL by EF, so the where condition can't be just any function that return boolean. It must be translatable Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rewrite it to combine all the properties into an array and check that for a match:

```cs
query.Where(e =>
    new[]{ e.Property1, e.Property2, e.Property3}
      .Any(p => EF.Functions.Like(p, pattern) )
);
```

The equivalent SQL is:

```sql
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM (VALUES
      (e.Property1),
      (e.Property2),
      (e.Property3)
    ) v(Prop)
    WHERE v.Prop LIKE @pattern
)
```

---

The equivalent `&&/AND` semantic is slightly different:

```cs
query.Where(e =>
    new[]{ e.Property1, e.Property2, e.Property3}
      .All(p => EF.Functions.Like(p, pattern) )
);
```

The equivalent SQL is a double-negative:

```sql
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM (VALUES
      (e.Property1),
      (e.Property2),
      (e.Property3)
    ) v(Prop)
    WHERE v.Prop NOT LIKE @pattern
)
```

Comment: Does this really get translated to sql?

Comment: @TimSchmelter If it's Entity Framework, yes, why wouldn't it? And I put it there more so that people understand how it works and how to do it in raw SQL

Comment: How about performance of such sql query? Sorry I never really understood those query execution plans, shame on me :O

Comment: @Charlieface: I'm not using EF much so i don't know, i just was suprised that `inMemoryCollection.Any(...)` will translate to a single pure sql query.

Comment: Should be fine, it will just loop through each field for every row. If you are doing `StartsWith` or `LIKE 'abc%'` then probably best not to do it on an indexed column

Comment: Why not indexed column?

Comment: Because it is unlikely to use the index in that case. But that only applies to [a pattern without a leading wildcard](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2010/06/sargable-why-string-is-slow/), or in EF `StartsWith` not `Contains`

Comment: I struggle to make this expression configurable. Something like Where(e => AnyPropertyLike(patterns, new [] { e.Property1, e.Property2 }), because EF.Functions.Like(string matchExpression, string pattern) takes string and not Expression as a parameter. Is it possible?

Comment: I don't know, how did the original code work, it should be the same.

Comment: No it isn't the same, because if I exfract EF.Functions. Like to separate method, it captures runtime value rather than expression. See @IvanStoev answer.

Comment: Sorry didn't realize you wanted it in a separate method.

Answer (score 3):

For top level `IQueryable<T>` (i.e. something which is not part of a query expression tree), this could be achieved with a custom extension method receiving value to match, predicate expression and list of expressions, and building `or` predicate from them. Something like this:

```
public static partial class QueryableExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<T> WhereAnyMatch<T, V>(this IQueryable<T> source,
        V value, Expression<Func<V, V, bool>> match,
        params Expression<Func<T, V>>[] itemsToMatch)
    {
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "e");
        Expression<Func<V>> arg = () => value; // to let EF Core bind a parameter rather tnan a constant
        var body = itemsToMatch
            .Select(item => Expression.Invoke(match, Expression.Invoke(item, parameter), arg.Body))
            .Aggregate<Expression>(Expression.OrElse);
        var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, parameter);
        return source.Where(predicate);
    }
}
```

and sample usage with your case would be:

```
.WhereAnyMatch(pattern, (item, arg) => EF.Functions.Like(item, arg),
    e => e.Property1, e => e.Property2, e => e.Property3);
```

Of course once you have that method, you could add other with commonly used match predicates, for instance `Like`:

```
public static partial class QueryableExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<T> WhereAnyLike<T>(this IQueryable<T> source,
        string pattern, params Expression<Func<T, string>>[] itemsToMatch)
        => source.WhereAnyMatch(pattern, (item, arg) => EF.Functions.Like(item, arg), itemsToMatch);
}
```

and the sample code will be simplified as

```
.WhereAnyLike(pattern, e => e.Property1, e => e.Property2, e => e.Property3);
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the methods to prevent having to retype similar code over and over again, was invented in the late '60s. They called it a procedure.

So why not extend IQueryable with a method `WhereLike`? Once you've done that, you can intertwine it with other LINQ statements, as if it was a proper LINQ method.

If you are not familiar with extension methods, read [extension methods demystified](https://www.dotnetcurry.com/csharp/995/extension-methods-csharp)

We can create an extension method for two or three Like statemens, or maybe for any finite number.

```
public static IQueryable<T> WhereLike<T>(this IQueryable<T> source,
    Func<T, string> propertySelector1,
    Func<T, string> propertySelector2,
    string pattern)
{
    return source.Where(item => EF.Functions.Like(propertySelector1(item, pattern)
                             || EF.Functions.Like(propertySelector2(item, pattern));
}
```

(similar for 3 property selectors)

Usage:

Get Customers who's first or last name are like "John%"

```
var result = dbContext.Customers.
    .WhereLike(customer => customer.FirstName,
               customer => customer.LastName,
               "John%");
```