# EF Core query using String.Contains

Tags: c#, ef-core-3.1

We have a requirement to searches a given term within a comma-separated string. The query is built so that it ignores possible leading and trailing spaces in the comma-separated string.
I came up with the following query which is running fine with EF 6.0

```
var trimmedTags = tags.Select(t => t.Trim()); // List of tags we need to look for    
return products.Where(p => trimmedTags.Any(t => ("," + p.Categories + ",").Contains("," + t + ",")) ||
                               trimmedTags.Any(t => ("," + p.Categories + ",").Contains(", " + t + ",")) ||
                               trimmedTags.Any(t => ("," + p.Categories + ",").Contains("," + t + " ,")) ||
                               trimmedTags.Any(t => ("," + p.Categories + ",").Contains(", " + t + " ,")));
```

This query is no longer running in EF Core 3.1 and throws the following error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Product>
    .Where(p => __trimmedTags_1
        .Any(t => ("," + p.Categories + ",").Contains("," + t + ",")) || __trimmedTags_1
        .Any(t => ("," + p.Categories + ",").Contains(", " + t + ",")) || __trimmedTags_1
        .Any(t => ("," + p.Categories + ",").Contains("," + t + " ,")) || __trimmedTags_1
        .Any(t => ("," + p.Categories + ",").Contains(", " + t + " ,")))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.'
```

My target table has millions of rows so client evaluation is unfortunately not an option. The EF Core team claims that `string.Contains` is supported but I can't figure out why my query is suddenly failing in EF Core.

Comment: I think you best bet at the moment is to iterate `trimmedTags` and build expression tree that you pass to `.Where` method. You can generate query products.Where(p => "," + p.Categories + ",".Contains(",tag1,")  || "," + p.Categories + ",".Contains(", tag2,") || "," + p.Categories + ",".Contains(",tag3,")); and that should work just fine.

Comment: Been a while since I used EF but does a ToList on trimmedTags (outside the query) fix the problem? That or you may try and use Ef.Functions.Like and simplify the comparison somehow

Comment: @dropoutcoder Thanks for the quick follow-up. That's exactly how I ended up solving the problem. Can you please convert your comment to an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 Using `ToList` was the first thing I tried, no luck :(

Comment: @GETah I don't see how `EF.Functions.Like` could help. The problem is not the `Contains` function, but it being part of `trimmedTags.Any(...)` call, where `trimmdeTags` being an in-memory collection. And the only supported operations with in-memory collections is `Coontains` with primitive value. So, are you sure you have solved your issue?

Comment: @IvanStoev OP was responding to the first comment about building an expression, not mine (which was just spit balling about finding a way *to* use Like, not that it was necessarily the solution)

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 My apologies, for some unknown reason I've assumed OP was responding to your comment.

Comment: @IvanStoev he did, on the line below :)

Comment: @GETah It seems someone already wrote an answer. I am not in a hunt for points. I am just happy to help :)

Comment: @dropoutcoder that's the spirit :) thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A different variations of this question often appear on SO, and the problem is always one and the same - even at the most current version (5.x) EF Core does not support operators on in-memory collections other than simple `Contains` with primitive value (or `Any` that can be turned into `Contains` like `x => memValues.Any(v => v == SomeExpr(x))`, with `==` operator being the essential).

The workaround is also one and the same - building dynamically expression - `||` (or) based for `Any` and `&&` (and) based for `All`.

This case requires `||`, and is similar to [How to simplify repetitive OR condition in Where(e => e.prop1.contains() || e.prop2.contains() || ...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66516488/how-to-simplify-repetitive-or-condition-in-wheree-e-prop1-contains-e-pr/66517999#66517999) but with value and field roles exchanged, so following is the helper method I would use:

```
public static partial class QueryableExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<T> WhereAnyMatch<T, V>(this IQueryable<T> source, IEnumerable<V> values, Expression<Func<T, V, bool>> match)
    {
        var parameter = match.Parameters[0];
        var body = values
            // the easiest way to let EF Core use parameter in the SQL query rather than literal value
            .Select(value => ((Expression<Func<V>>)(() => value)).Body)
            .Select(value => Expression.Invoke(match, parameter, value))
            .Aggregate<Expression>(Expression.OrElse);
        var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, parameter);
        return source.Where(predicate);
    }
}
```

Note that this works only for top level query expressions. If you need something like this for something which is part of a query expression tree (like collection navigation property), you'd need different type of helper function or some library which allows expression injection.

Luckily that's not the case here, so the above helper method can be used directly by passing the `trimmedTags` and the condition for each tag value, e.g.

```
return products.WhereAnyMatch(trimmedTags, (p, t) => 
    ("," + p.Categories + ",").Contains("," + t + ",") ||
    ("," + p.Categories + ",").Contains(", " + t + ",") ||
    ("," + p.Categories + ",").Contains("," + t + " ,") ||
    ("," + p.Categories + ",").Contains(", " + t + " ,"));
```

Comment: Awesome! Working beautifully. Thanks a lot.