# Duplicate parameter insertion exception on building query by expressions

Tags: c#, duplicates, frameworks, expression, entity

I'm trying to do fuzzy matching in C# and I'm stuck on a problem I have no idea how to resolve. The parameter seems to not be flushed after the operation, even though I'm using a new context in every call.

Code of main:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var context = new Context())
            {
                context.Database.Migrate();
            }

            GetPersons().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            GetPersons().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }

        static async Task<IEnumerable<Person>> GetPersons()
        {
            var lastNameStrings = new List<string> { "Foo", "oob", "oba", "bar" };

            using (var context = new Context())
            {
                var query = context.Persons.AsQueryable().WhereAnyMatch(lastNameStrings, 
                    (f, y) => f.LastName.Contains(y));
                return await query.ToListAsync();
            }
        }
```

Helper method made by Ivan Stoev at https://stackoverflow.com/a/66624611/12646728). Unfortunately my karma won't let me comment under the source comment.:

```
        public static IQueryable<T> WhereAnyMatch<T, V>(this IQueryable<T> source, IEnumerable<V> values, Expression<Func<T, V, bool>> match)
        {
            var parameter = match.Parameters[0];

            var body = values
                // the easiest way to let EF Core use parameter in the SQL query rather than literal value
                .Select(value => ((Expression<Func<V>>)(() => value)).Body)
                .Select(value => Expression.Invoke(match, parameter, value))
                .Aggregate<Expression>(Expression.OrElse);
            var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, parameter);

            return source.Where(predicate);
        }
```

The method works fine for the first time. If I run it the second time and at least one substring overlaps (like new List { **"Foo"**, "ooo" } then I get:
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
An item with the same key has already been added. Key: f

What is happening here? If I'm using new context with every call, the expression should be reset as well, right?

I tried debugging it line-by-line, checked the query string and it looks as expected (proper WHERE clauses for first name, followed by AND proper WHERE clauses for last name - not included in this example). Tried replacing parameters, even making changes to Utils classes that insert to Dictionary.

Comment: Is ther are reason you are you using   `GetPersons().GetAwaiter().GetResult();` instead of `await GetPersons()`

Comment: No specific reason, it's just for making a quick example. I use await in the main program