# EF Core 5 - In memory object list filtering not working against DBset

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I need to filter against a DBset using a list of objects passed in as a variable to my repo.

The following worked in EF6

```
List<MyFilterObj> incomingList = [{A: 1, B: 2}, {A: 3, B: 4}]

return await context.MyDBset
                .Where(x => incomingList.Any(v =>
                                v.A == x.A &&
                                v.B == x.B)).ToListAsync();
```

If I try this same approach in EF Core 5 I get the following error:

*The LINQ expression (MyDBset) could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.*

I can't seperate the incoming list into seperate A and B lists as the combination is essential to the filter accuracy. Otherwise I could have used this approach

```
return await context.MyDBset
                    .Where(x => incomingListA.Contains(x.A) &&
                                    incomingListB.Contains(x.B)).ToListAsync();
```

This approach does work in EF Core 5

Basically I want EF to translate my query into something like:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable AS m
Where (m.A = 1 AND m.B = 2) OR (m.A = 3 AND m.B = 4)
```

If I loop through my incomingList adding "where" filters to a query the resultant SQL uses "AND" instead of "OR" like so:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable AS m
Where (m.A = 1 AND m.B = 2) AND (m.A = 3 AND m.B = 4)
```

Right now my work around involves binging the result set into memory with some basic filters then running an in memory filter using the original syntax. This is obviously not ideal.

Any suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since EF Core is not willing to translate such expression (it's a well known limitation that `Contains` with primitive value is the only supported operation on in-memory collection in L2E query since it directly translates to SQL `IN` operator), you have to do it yourself. `Any` is basically equivalent of `Or` as you mentioned, so for not so big list and *top level* query it could easily be done by using some predicate builder implementation to dynamically build  `||` predicate. Or directly using the the `Expression` class methods as in this custom extension method from my answer to [How to simplify repetitive OR condition in Where(e => e.prop1.contains() || e.prop2.contains() || ...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66516488/how-to-simplify-repetitive-or-condition-in-wheree-e-prop1-contains-e-pr/66517999#66517999):

```
public static partial class QueryableExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<T> WhereAnyMatch<T, V>(this IQueryable<T> source, IEnumerable<V> values, Expression<Func<T, V, bool>> match)
    {
        var parameter = match.Parameters[0];
        var body = values
            // the easiest way to let EF Core use parameter in the SQL query rather than literal value
            .Select(value => ((Expression<Func<V>>)(() => value)).Body)
            .Select(value => Expression.Invoke(match, parameter, value))
            .Aggregate<Expression>(Expression.OrElse);
        var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, parameter);
        return source.Where(predicate);
    }
}
```

with sample usage for your scenario:

```
context.MyDBset
    .WhereAnyMatch(incomingList, (x, v) => v.A == x.A && v.B == x.B)
```

Normally instead of `Expression.Invoke` helper utilities like this would use custom `ExpressionVisitor` to replace the parameters of the source expression (thus simulation a "call"), which produces more naturally looking query expression, but for EF Core it doesn't really matter since it recognizes and correctly translates invocation expressions inside the expression tree.

But just in case `Expression.Invoke` doesn't work, here is the parameter replacing version -   it should work with all query providers. First, the helpers

```
public static partial class ExpressionBuilder
{
    public static Expression ReplaceParameter(this Expression source, ParameterExpression parameter, Expression value)
        => new ParameterReplacer { Parameter = parameter, Value = value }.Visit(source);

    class ParameterReplacer : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        public ParameterExpression Parameter;
        public Expression Value;
        protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
            => node == Parameter ? Value : node;
    }
}
```

and then simply replace the invocation

```
.Select(value => Expression.Invoke(match, parameter, value))
```

with

```
.Select(value => match.Body.ReplaceParameter(match.Parameters[1], value))
```

because specifically here we are reusing the first parameter (`var parameter = match.Parameters[0];`), otherwise it should be replaced as well.

Comment: I gave this a try with my actual query but got an error
var result = await context.Courses
                    .Include(c => c.Grade)
                    .Include(c => c.Subject)
                    .WhereAnyMatch(courseDefinitions, (course, courseDef) => 
                        courseDef.Subject == course.Subject.Code &&
                        courseDef.AcademicYear == course.AcademicYear &&
                        courseDef.Grade == course.Grade.Code &&
                        courseDef.Language == course.Language)
                    .ToArrayAsync();

Comment: The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Course>() ..... could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form....

Comment: What EFC version are you using? Just to make sure `Invoke` is supported (it was broken in some versions).

Comment: We are currently using version 5.0.1

Comment: Hmm, it should work there. Please try the "non invocation" version and let me know. If it doesn't work, we need to look at the concrete usage (hope there are no [`NotMapped`] or `Ignore`d properties used in the conditions? or non primitive types like custom classes for properties of `courseDef` used for comparison).  I know it sounds weird, but I was using the above many times and it usually works. Or does it work if you do the same manually, for instance with 2 element list. But let first see if the problem is with the invocation.

Comment: Actually I've tried it on the latest EFC 5.0.6 and the problem is with invocation (weird!). The "non invocation" version  (from the update) works as usual.

Comment: Thanks so much, Using the non-invocation version did work!!

Comment: Also since 3.0 there is a build in [`ReplacingExpressionVisitor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.query.replacingexpressionvisitor?view=efcore-5.0)